# How to merge zero values (vector(0) with metric values in PromQL

Tags: monitoring, prometheus, promql

I'm using [flexlm_exporter](https://github.com/mjtrangoni/flexlm_exporter) to export my license usage to Prometheus and from Prometheus to custom service (Not Grafana).

As you know Prometheus hides missing values.

However, I need those missing values in my metric values, therefore I added to my prom query `or vector(0)`

For example:

```
flexlm_feature_used_users{app="vendor_lic-server01",name="Temp"} or vector(0)
```

This query adds a empty metric with zero values.

My question is if there's a way to merge the zero vector with each metric values?

Edit:

I need grouping, at least for a user and name labels, so vector(0) is probably not the best option here?
[image: Example query with a specific user with missing values and zero vector]

I tried multiple solutions in different StackOverflow threads, however, nothing works.

Please assist.

Answer (score 17):

It would help if you used `Absent` with labels to convert the value from 1 to zero, use `clamp_max`

```
( Metrics{label=“a”} OR clamp_max(absent(notExists{label=“a”}),0))
+
( Metrics2{label=“a”} OR clamp_max(absent(notExists{label=“a”}),0)
```

`Vector(0)` has no label.

`clamp_max(Absent(notExists{label=“a”},0)` is 0 with label.

Comment: Could this be leveraged to tackle multiple time series at the same time? I.e. if `Metrics{label=“a”}` returns multiple time series.

Answer (score 3):

If you do `sum(flexlm_feature_used_users{app="vendor_lic-server01",name="Temp"} or vector(0))` you should get what you're looking for, but you'll lose possibility to do `group by`, since `vector(0)` doesn't have any labels.

Comment: You right, but I need the grouping. So any other solution probably without vector(0), since I have to get at least user and name labels

Comment: I think you should be able to manually add them with recording rules, but this could be painful, if the list of values is long and/or not fixed. But then it's better to find a way for metric to always contain a value, even when 0.

Answer (score 1):

I needed a similar thing, and ended up flattening the options. What worked for me was something like:

```
(sum by xyz(flexlm_feature_used_users{app="vendor_lic-server01",name="Temp1"} + sum by xyz(flexlm_feature_used_users{app="vendor_lic-server01",name="Temp2"}) or

sum by xyz(flexlm_feature_used_users{app="vendor_lic-server01",name="Temp1"} or

sum by xyz(flexlm_feature_used_users{app="vendor_lic-server01",name="Temp2"}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no an easy generic way to fill gaps in returned time series with zeroes in Prometheus. But this can be easily done via `default` operator in [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/):

```
flexlm_feature_used_users{app="vendor_lic-server01",name="Temp"} default 0
```

The `q default N` fills gaps with the given default value `N` per each time series returned from `q`. See more details in [MetricsQL docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html).