# Time series from Prometheus source: how to set nulls as zero?

Tags: counter, prometheus, grafana

Working in Docker Grafana 8.1.5. Using time series graph, I'm plotting a `Prometheus` `Counter` source (that has one `label`) as a `time series` (by label), and need to **fill all null/missing values as zeros**.

This is the query applied to the `Prometheus` `counter` source, plotting the label `code`:

```
my_metric{code!=""}
```

The graph display works (just need to see the current counter value for each label variant, and the difference within the selected time range), but the new Grafana `time series graph` is missing an option that the `Graph (old)` has under `Display > Stacking and null value > null value: null as zero`, hence it now ends up with broken lines when null values occur.

Unfortunately, I cannot use the `Graph (old)` chart as I need the legend value `difference`, which only is available in the new `time series` graph.

I tried to add `or on() vector(0)` to the end of the query, but the condition does not get applied to the data series for each label variant, it rather adds a new data series all filled with zeros...

Thanks for any suggestions !

Answer (score 21):

I had this issue as well and I was not able to use only `or on() vector(0)` as you mentioned because the main query was returning `NaN`. In my case I had a division by zero.

I could get around of it by first evaluate if the query has a value `>= 0` and then use the `or on() vector(0)`. Try something similar to:

```
((my_metric{code!=""}) >= 0) OR on() vector(0)
```

Comment: this does not work in my situation to fill all null/missing values as zero, it also simply adds another, separate line that consists of zeros

Comment: Hey @pete19 , could you please post a screenshot of the result? It is a little bit hard to understand your problem only by describing it.

Comment: Felipe, this works for some queries, but want to note that one often needs to wrap the query then in an extra set of parentheses `()` if the result is used in other functions...

Comment: @pete19  I am glad that you made it to work. I edited my answer with your information. In case you think that my post could answer your question, would you mind to acceptas a answer? I thank you in advance

Comment: @Felipe very nice trick on that ` OR on() vector(0)`. Works very well where you want to show a RAG status, and panel doesn't like null series.

Answer (score 12):

The following technique can be used for filling gaps in a single time series returned from the query `q`:

```
sum(q) or vector(0)
```

The `q` is wrapped into `sum()` in order to drop all the labels for a time series returned from `q`, so the time series can be matched with `vector(0)` time series according to [matching rules for `or` operator](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators). The query without `sum()`: `q or on() vector(0)` would return two time series on the graph instead of a single time series: one time series from `q` with its own set of labels and another time series with zero labels and with zero value where the `q` time series contains gaps.

Unfortunately Prometheus doesn't provide an easy ability to fill gaps with zeroes if `q` returns multiple time series with distinct labelsets. Other Prometheus-like solutions such as VictoriaMetrics (I work on it) provides `default` operator for this case. For example, the following [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html) query fills gaps with zeroes for all the time series returned from `q`:

```
q default 0
```

Comment: I think everything should be nested inside `sum()` like this: `sum(q or vector(0))`. At least that's what worked for me

Answer (score 0):

### if you want to default 0 with labels, you can do it:

**solution(promql)**

```
my_metric_1{aaa="your_filter_val1",bbb="your_filter_val2"} or group by (aaa,bbb) ({aaa="your_filter_val1",bbb="your_filter_val2"}) (my_metric_2) < bool 0
```

**background**

`my_metric_1{aaa="a", bbb="b"}`

the metric can be null,

`my_metric_2{aaa="a", bbb="b"}`

the metric always existed.

**explain**

```
vector_with_labels(can nil) or vector2_with_labels(always 0)
```

**others**

maybe it is easy if use`victoriametrics`,